# Quantum Tunneling

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, quantum-tunneling

Does Quantum tunneling prove there is a chance of big bang after the heat death of the universe? I mean how can we say it can produce another Big Bang in some years.

Comment: who says this is true?

Comment: I came across this in many times. So many told me this will occur.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question as "Does quantum tunneling..." rather than "How does quantum tunneling..." Or link to a source that says this is the case.

Comment: @Chris I edited the question. And sorry for mistake in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The birth of the universe is a matter of theoretical research. In the papers one can find the vocabulary of tunneling and of bounce cosmology, [here is an example:](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0682)

> The probable trajectory of the ground state wave function of the universe arises through a quantum tunneling by gravitational instantons. We calculate the quantum tunneling rate for a n>2 dimensional closed Friedmann-Robertson-Walker universe with a positive cosmological constant. In four dimensions, by using of the holographic principle, the tunneling rate is related to the maximal entropy of the early universe after quantum tunneling.

A more [recent one :](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08468)

> We investigate Euclidean wormholes in Einstein gravity with a massless scalar field in de Sitter space. Euclidean wormholes are possible due to the analytic continuation of the time as well as complexification of fields, where we need to impose the classicality after the Wick-rotation to the Lorentzian signatures. For some parameters, wormholes are preferred than Hawking-Moss instantons, and hence wormholes can be more fundamental than Hawking-Moss type instantons. Euclidean wormholes can be interpreted in three ways: (1) classical big bounce, (2) either tunneling from a small to a large universe or a creation of a collapsing and an expanding universe from nothing, and (3) either a transition from a contracting to a bouncing phase or a creation of two expanding universes from nothing. These various interpretations shed some light on challenges of singularities. In addition, these will help to understand tensions between various kinds of quantum gravity theories.

So it is not a matter of "prove", it is a matter of whether the birth of the universe can be **modeled** using quantum tunneling, and there are theoretical proposals which use quantum tunneling. It is an open theoretical research field, and it will take a long time, imo, for one of the proposals to come up with a prediction of testable observations for such a model of the birth of the universe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really removed confusion on me.

Comment: This is a very good answer!